# как сделать переход на предыдущую активити аппаратной кнопкой назад

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle

Есть приложение из двух `Activity`. На второй `Activity` при нажатии аппаратной кнопки "Назад", приложение сворачивается. При восстановлении через кнопку "Меню", появляется предыдущая `Activity`.

Вопрос: почему сворачивается и как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "назад" (аппаратной) осуществлялся просто переход на предыдущую `Activity`?

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.borsch">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Код, вызывающий вторую `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void btnHistoryClick (View view) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

}
```

Comment: Вторую активити запускаю кнопкой в первой. Простите мою неграмотность, я только начал учиться, что за флаги и где в манифесте найти такой параметр?

Comment: покажите весь манифест и код, вызывающий вторую активити, начиная от создания интента.

Comment: ну вы не вызываете вторую активити, вы всего лишь устанавливаете в первой активити макет второй

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `setContentView(View view)`, используйте Intent, так как `setContentView` не запускает `Activity` а просто вставляет макет второго `Activity` в `MainActivity`.

Делайте так:

```
public void btnHistoryClick (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

А в `HistoryActivity` при нажатии на кнопку назад:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Я вам советую почитать этот [туториал](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity.html)

Comment: все верно, только переопределять `onBackPressed()` совершенно лишнее ,а в таком виде даже вредное, так как при каждом переходе будут создаваться ненужные объекты, добавляя работы GC, одного `finish()` вполне достаточно, только вот `finish()` и так вызывается в супер-классе.

Comment: то есть при переходе в HistoryActivity не завершать MainActivity методом finish()? А потом в HistoryActivity завершить просто финишем?

Comment: Вы советовали в ответе прочитать туториал, почему бы вам тоже его не прочитать. Нигде никаких финишей, в первой переход на вторую и все, во второй ничего для возврата делать не нужно, в системе уже все реализовано

Comment: Извините, но я знаю что и без финишей заработает. Этот пример наглядно демонстрирует переход и завершение `Activity` и ответ полностью соответствует заданному вопросу.

Comment: На мой взгляд пример (вторая часть) наглядно демонстрирует нерациональное расходование ресурсов устройства и дублирование имеющейся в системе функциональности, но это ваш ответ. Просто я счел нужным обратить на это внимание, так как новичек может не знать, что это "наглядный пример", который бесполезен в реальном использовании

Comment: Я бы поспорил бы насчет "бесполезен в реальном использовании". А насчет ресурсов согласен.

Comment: Так, ребята, дайте я в ваш спор влезу, чтобы уточнить!
Создаем интент, стартуем его и переходим в Активити_Два. По нажатию на физическую кнопку "бэк" возвращаемся в первую активити, а вторая уничтожается. Зачем переопределять метод onBackPressed() и пихать туда finish()?

Comment: Спор уже закончен)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно переопределить метод во второй активити, который будет слушать событие нажатие на кнопку "Назад". По-моему, это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Предыдущаяактивити.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Нет, к сожалению всё осталось так же...

Comment: Вы не запускаете активити, вы просто устанавливаете в первой активити разметку второй. Что бы запустить вторую активити воспользуйтесь следующим кодом                                                 
                                                                                                            
        public void btnHistoryClick (View view) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(this, втораяактивити.class);
               startActivity(intent);

         }

Answer (score 0):

код, который нужно добавить в первую активити:

```
Button btn = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button); // находим кнопку
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnCLickListener){    // даем кнопке обработчик
Intent intent = new Intent (this, HistoryActivity.class); //создаем интент
startActivity(intent);                                    // отправляемся в лучший мир
}
```

И больше ничего!